# PrimeFaces Push: subscription to multiple dynamic channels

Tags: jsf, primefaces, push

I have a `p:dataTable` showing a financial instrument and real-time prices in each row, and I want to setup broadcast channels using `p:socket`, one channel for each row. The goal is that when a new price arrives for a single instrument, I am able to update only its cell in order to have better performance.

First I tried with replicating the chat example from [showcase's chat example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/chat.jsf), with the subscription of the dynamic channel from the server side, but this way the client is not able to get which channel the message is on (and does `p:socket` handle multiple channels?).

Then, I tried with inserting `p:socket` in the dataTable:

```
<p:dataTable var="instrument"  … >
    <p:socket onMessage="handleMessage(#{instrument.id})" channel="/price" autoConnect="false" 
                                      widgetVar="subscriber_#{instrument.id}" /> 
    …
</p:dataTable>
```

and on the server side:

```
for (Instrument instrument : instruments) {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("subscriber_" +instrument.getId() + ".connect('/" + instrument.getId() + "')");
}
```

But this throws an error in the client:

```
ReferenceError: subscriber_123 is not defined
```

Are there any other ways? I have no problem in managing the subscription either on the client or on the server side, the only important thing is that I don’t want to push all the prices to all the clients.

Using PrimeFaces 3.4.1

Answer (score 0):

If you are still not able to make it work, here's how you can dynamically subscribe/connect to a channel.

`RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("subscriber.connect('/" + instrument.getId() + "')");`

You don't need to have multiple `<p:socket>` in your datatable. A single socket is enough to handle all your pub/sub.